# Create a grid of 1000*1000 in flutter

Tags: dart, flutter

i'm looking for create a grid of 1000*1000 box. User should be able to click on one and zoom in. Do anyone knows a material to do so ?

I tried to do a gridview, way to long to be initialize for only 2000 unity

Thanks for reading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If performance is a problem, use a `CustomPainter` and a `GestureDetector` to handle painting and gesture detection manually. Make sure that you only paint the boxes which are visible on screen.